# How do you create a net.tcp endpoint to an Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: wcf, tcp, azure-cloud-services

This has to be a pretty simple task.  I have an Azure Cloud Service that works just fine with HTTP and HTTPS.  Now I want to create a net.tcp connection to the cloud service.  The first thing I discover is that net.tcp is not supported by IIS Express.  That's fine.  So I try switching to regular IIS and all I get when I try to run the application is a 404 error.  If I was building an WCF Web Application, I would get a form that allows me to select (and build) the virtual directory for the application, but there's no analog for this in the Cloud Service.

I can take a fresh 'Cloud Service' project build using visual studio, make no changes to it except change IIS Express to IIS.  When I launch it, I get a 404 error in the web browser.

Does anyone have a working example of tcp.net (with IIS Express or standard IIS) in a Cloud Service?

Answer (score 0):

This [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/series/developing-windows-azure-and-web-services/02) by the Azure team is a great overview and cleared up a lot of conceptual issues I had.  An Azure Cloud Service is a container around one or more virtual machines.  The virtual machines basically come in two flavors: Web Role and Worker Role.  What threw me is the description that the Worker Role was intended for background processes: not true.  A Web Role is basically a VM with IIS, a Worker Role is basically a VM without IIS.  Since the off-the-shelf IIS doesn't have net.tcp installed, you have to jump through hoops in order to get the protocol installed.  Instead, the Worker Role can be used as a self-hosted web service.  If you want the performance and throughput of TCP, this appears to be the direction to go.